# Start-ChocolateyProcessAsAdmin can't find script in parent folder

Tags: powershell, chocolatey

I have this very basic `ChocolateyInstall.ps1` script that should call another Powershell script in a parent folder. This is my project structure:

```
project/
  service-install.ps1
  tools/
    chocolatey/
      ChocolateyInstall.ps1
```

And this is my `ChocolateyInstall.ps1`:

```
# Install the windows service

Start-ChocolateyProcessAsAdmin -ExeToRun "powershell" -Statements "./service-install.ps1" -WorkingDirectory "..\..\"
```

When installing the build package, the `ChocolateyInstall.ps1` fails with this error:

```
<S S="Error">./service-install.ps1 : The term './service-install.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again._x000D__x000A_</S>
<S S="Error">At line:7 char:9_x000D__x000A_</S>
<S S="Error">+         ./service-install.ps1_x000D__x000A_</S>
<S S="Error">+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~_x000D__x000A_</S>
<S S="Error">    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (./service-install.ps1:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException_x000D__x000A_</S>
<S S="Error">    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException_x000D__x000A_</S>
<S S="Error"> _x000D__x000A_</S>
```

I need to run the script with the `project/` directory as workdir.

Why isn't the service install script properly executed / found? I already tried the examples of the [command](https://chocolatey.org/docs/helpers-start-chocolatey-process-as-admin#examples) but still can't get it to work.

Comment: I have, no difference. And I don't think this is running in a cmd prompt since I specify the exe to run as `powershell`

Answer (score 1):

In most Chocolatey packages, you will see a line similar to this:

```
$ScriptRoot = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
```

This will give you the location of the currently executing script, i.e. the chocolateyInstall.ps1 file.  From there, you should be able to "find" the script that you want to execute.